# No CameraInfo received on Rviz, No Image Received

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get camera data from the turtlebot to my workstation.  The netbook is running 10.04 and the workstation laptop is running 10.10.

On the turtlebot netbook I configured the IP settings, and ran the teleop successfully. I would like to now grab camera data from the turtlebot kinect.

On the netbook I ran

> rosrun turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch

On the turtlebot workstation I run

> rosrun rviz rviz

I click add, camera, then under the display bar, under Camera, it says "Status Warning." Image Topic I select camera>rgb>Image_raw. I get an error and No CameraInfo received on [/camera_info]

I have tried not only Image_raw, but a few of the other selections, and non of them seem to work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62644/no-camerainfo-received-on-rviz,-no-image-received/) by [djchase88](https://answers.ros.org/users/4883/djchase88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-05-13**:
Can your netbook and workstation ping each other by host name?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-04**:
Yes, check the network setup (executing roswtf on both machines also helps to find problems). Can you see the image if you add an "Image" display (not "Camera")? Do you get output for `rostopic hz camera/rgb/camera_info`?

**Comment by [niraj007](https://answers.ros.org/users/26349/niraj007/) on 2016-03-29**:
I had the same problem. I follow http://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln and use usb_camera. I can see the image if I add "Image" and subscribe to usb_cam/image_raw. Thanks for idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I tried the ROS system for the first time, I didnt have a netbook yet and so I used the Live Version from the USB stick. However, this is not working. You cant use it to run RViz and subscribe to a camera. Just in case anybody has the same issue some time.

---

Originally posted by [tlanglot](https://answers.ros.org/users/14301/tlanglot/) with karma: 16 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0